# finding physical address using page table walkthrough

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

looking to access process page table entries to find physical address of a process data passed as an argument to char drivers read routine. here is code for the same for
Linux x86-32bit with PAE mode disabled

```
    static unsigned long getDirEntry(const pgd_t *pgd, void *address)
    {
         unsigned long d_index;
         unsigned long *pgd_array = (unsigned long *)pgd;
         unsigned long tmp;

         unsigned long t = (unsigned long)address;
         d_index = t >> 22;
         tmp = pgd_array[d_index];
         tmp = tmp >> 12;
         tmp = tmp << 12;
         return tmp;
    } 

    static unsigned long getPageTableEntry(unsigned long d, void *address)
    {
         unsigned long t;
         unsigned long *pte_array = (unsigned long *)d;
         unsigned long tmp;

         t = (unsigned long)address;
         t = t << 10;
         t = t >> 22;

         tmp = pte_array[t];
         tmp = tmp >> 12;
         tmp = tmp << 12;
         return tmp;
    }

    ssize_t ptd_read(struct file *filp,char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *fpos)
    {
        unsigned long d, pte, t;
        unsigned int pfn, pfn2;
        struct page *pptr, *pptr2;

        struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;
        pgd_t *pgd = mm->pgd;
        d = getDirEntry(pgd,buf);
        pfn = d >> 12;
        pptr = pfn_to_page(pfn);
        printk(KERN_INFO "struct page = %p\n",pptr);
        kptr1 = kmap(pptr);
        pte = getPageTableEntry((unsigned long)kptr1,buf);
        pfn2 = pte >>12;
        pptr2 = pfn_to_page(pfn2);
        kptr2 = kmap(pptr2);
        printk(KERN_INFO "KERNEL:Frame mapped to page  = %p\n",kptr2);
        t = (unsigned long)buf;
        t = t << 20;
        t = t >> 20;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Value of string inside physical page = %s\n",(char *)kptr2+t);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code works fine on all 32-bit kernels with PAE disabled. Code would need changes to work on kernels with PAE enabled (which is now default on most distributions), 
Need inputs/suggestions to port above module to PAE enabled kernels, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have done page walkthrough statically no dynamically so it will now work when PAE is enabled so for that the macros PAGE_SHIFT and may more is needed so refer the below link

[It gives you knowledge about all this macros](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)